¿Cómo puedo hacer que el elemento main con display:flex tome todo el espacio disponible?
Tengo en mi html una jerarquía de elementos: html > body > main > div#box. A este div lo quiero centrar tanto horizontalmente como verticalmente. Para ello me veo en la necesidad de utilizar flexbox en main. El problema está en que main no toma todo el alto de la página, o más bien, no toma todo el espacio disponible. Lo curioso es que esto solo pasa cuando le doy a main el display:flex.
¿Qué debería hacer? Les dejo el código a continuación.


* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 14px;
}
body {
    min-height: 100%;
}

main {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100dvh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}

div#box {
    background-color: red;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
<body>
    <main>
        <div id="box"></div>
    </main>
</body>




Prueba dándole el 100% de la altura y el ancho al HTML, al BODY y al MAIN. O trata con width: 100vw y height: 100vh en el MAIN.

Sería necesario saber realmente que quieres maquetar en la página en cuestión:
Si únicamente quieres un elemento en el centro y poner ahí todo, o hay más cosas. Ya que eso cambia la posible solución. Voy a dar por hecho que quieres poner un main y luego casi todo dentro del cuadro rojo (o lo que es lo mismo, mantener el HTML), para ello lo más sencillo sería hacer el body flex:


* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    display: flex;
    /* al ocupar el 100% de la altura, se alineara verticalmente correcto*/
    align-items: center;
}

main {
    /* Si quiero meter mas cosas que el "box" mantenemos el main a nivel de html */

    /* 
        necesitaremos display flex 
        y width 100% ya que está dentro de un contenedor flex, 
          así haremos que este contenedor ocupe el 100%
    */
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    /* 
        alineamos horizontalmente a la zona central los elementos, 
        que en este caso solo tenemos un hijo
    */
    justify-content: center;
}

div#box {
    background-color: red;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
  <body>
    <main>
      <div id="box"></div>
    </main>
  </body>



Aunque se vea raro pruébalo en un html. De esta forma evitamos también jugar con tamaños y así y se adecua a cualquier pantalla.
En cualquier caso te facilito esta guía:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/
